# Java, Maven Jar file versioning parts

Tags: java, maven, version-control

Hi Java and Maven Gurus,

I have a question about Maven Components/Dependency/Jar version numbering system. 
I have noticed that there is a .M1 or .Beta or .Alpha at the end of the jar file's version number. 
Let us take this Hibernate library/module for example:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core

```
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>5.4.9.Final</version>
```

Which can also be:

```
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>6.0.0.Alpha2</version>
```

Or can also be:

```
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>6.5.32.M1</version>
```

If I am not mistaken 'M1' stands for Milestone 1 for 'version 6.5.32.M1'.
Having experienced Waterfall development before, I have a gut feeling of what an Alpha or Beta or a Gold build is. 
So in this case, is M1 (Milestone 1) have a similar purpose or idea?

Thanks, 
Artanis Zeratul

Comment: A Milestone is usually a version that is not yet final. But the exact usage depends on the project, which means that the hibernate people need to answer that.

Comment: This isn’t really related to anything other than version naming, which is ultimately arbitrary. Milestones are just that: checkpoints on the way to a release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that M1 stands for Milestone 1. Please check the following line at https://hibernate.org/search/roadmap/

> Dates are generally omitted: milestones are released regularly, the
>   Final release is tagged when it’s considered stable.

Comment: noted and thanks. but hopefully you answered, without bias to Hibernate. I just used hibernate as an example for this one. Because this doesn't happen in Hibernate. It also happened to Spring or Springboot too.